# Python print giving an error

Tags: python, printing, syntax-error

I am trying to execute the below code which is giving an error:

```
>>> the_world_is_flat = True
>>> # this is a comment
... text = "# but this is not since quotes"
>>> if the_world_is_flat:
...     print("Be careful not to fall off!")
... print(text) ## why is this error
  File "<stdin>", line 3
    print(text) ## why is this error
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

But the below code is working fine.

```
>>> the_world_is_flat = True
>>> # this is a comment
... text = "# but this is not since quotes"
>>> if the_world_is_flat:
...     print("Be careful not to fall off!")
...     print(text) ## no error
...
Be careful not to fall off!
# but this is not since quotes
>>>
```

Please let me know why such a difference is there.

Comment: Indentation matters in Python

Comment: I think python interpreter considering the next `print` inside the if and detecting indentation error.

Comment: If you're typing into a python console, you need to press enter again (input an empty line) to end your `if` block. When the prompt shows `>>>`, it's ready to accept a new statement.

Comment: you are getting an indentation error, i would recommend using an IDE to get the grips of `python` syntax before writing in the console, you can use IDLE which is shipped with the python download

Answer (score 0):

If you had a file with a python script in, both would work.

When you're using the interacting python environment, it's useful to pay attention to the prompt at the start of each line. The `...` is a continuation prompt, meaning python is expecting you to  continue the code block you started - the `if` statement. By not indenting `print(text)` you are ending that block, when the interactive python interpreter is expecting it to carry on.

Press `enter` one more time when you've finished the `if` statement so that you get back to the `>>>` prompt:

```
>>> if the_world_is_flat:
...     print("Be careful not to fall off!")
...
Be careful not to fall off!
>>> print(text)
```

Comment: Or you can also give four spaces to put the same into the block.

Comment: True, but they knew that, as it was in the question ;)

Answer (score 0):

In the terminal

the if condition not work like as from file
if you use if condition in terminal. Need to close the if condition then make print

```
>>> the_world_is_flat = True
>>> text = "# but this is not since quotes"
>>> if the_world_is_flat:
...   print("Be careful not to fall off!")
... print (text)
```

use like above it give error. Because the if condition not close.
so use:

```
>>> if the_world_is_flat:
...   print("Be careful not to fall off!")
... 
Be careful not to fall off!
>>> print (text)
# but this is not since quotes
```